# How to add additional labels in log stream with grafana loki

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki

i have like 2 or 3 clusters that i am collecting logs from centrally using grafana loki. I want to able to distinguish the logs from each of environment, each environment is its own k8s cluster.
But i still see only the stock labels that are added and not the ones i am trying to add

Here's how i tried to add the labels using external_labels:

```
promtail:
  enabled: true
  config:
    logLevel: info
    serverPort: 3100
    clients:
      - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
  external_labels:
    cluster: prod
  scrape_configs:
    - job_name: kubernetes
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
      label_config:
        external_labels:
          cluster: prod
```

Is this the correct approach or am i missing something?

Comment: Will [this](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/configuration/#example-static-config) help?

Comment: @markalex Hi thanks for giving your input. I am using kubernetes_sd_config for kubernetes and it seems that it doesn't have the options to specify labels like:
labels:n
  env: dev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following configuration worked for me:

```
promtail:
  enabled: true
  config:
    logLevel: info
    serverPort: 3100
    clients:
      - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
        external_labels:
          cluster: "prod"
scrape_configs:
- job_name: kubernetes
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
```